# Create a custom Catalog Grid for Marketplace Extension

Tags: magento

I'm trying to create simple custom extension marketplace. For customer, there is the diferences in shop. The intention is to enable other vendors sell the Magento site transparently. The control and access of the seller is only administrative.

I created access for sellers users in the administrator and there is a section for them to control their products. But sellers do not have the ability to register the products. I will manually register the product with admin user. I created a user_id attribute the product to associate each product with a salesman. There will be no way of two or more sellers sell the same product.

I'm difculdade to create a tab in my extension that contains all products associated with a seller, so he can just edit the price and stock magento catalog just for your products (remember I linked product vs seller in the register of products ). My initial idea was to extend the catalog model and create a grid with only the products in such sellers, so they could edit just these two basic information (price and qty). But I'm not finding a way to make it "elegant" way (so as not to break the core or MVC Magento).

Note: I am trying to avoid creating a new model just to save price and qty, and in some way try to replace this date in catalog product model. I want to make the Magento native way as possible.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you wouldn't be breaking any conventions from doing this. The purpose of a model is to manipulate data and host most of the business logic. Therefore, it is elegant since other programmers will understand your code.

My suggestion is to class override the two models in the model so that it displays for the seller's products.